# Limit the exposed attributes of the entities using a DTO with a datatable

Tags: spring, hibernate, datatables

I am trying to limit the number of attributes of the entity via a dto and display them using a datatable. I've found the implementation as well but each time a post request is sent it throws ("No primary or default constructor found for interface java.util.function.Function") on postman and "java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.util.function.Function.()" on the console in STS.

I've created constructors for both the entity and the DTO to no avail.

this is the implementaion i am following :(https://github.com/darrachequesne/spring-data-jpa-datatables#limit-the-exposed-attributes-of-the-entities) 
here is the controller for this 
 https://github.com/darrachequesne/spring-data-jpa-datatables/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/datatables/repository/EmployeeRepositoryTest.java

this is my controller:

```
    @JsonView(DataTablesOutput.View.class)
    @RequestMapping(value = "api/libraryitemspojo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public DataTablesOutput<LibraryItemDataTableDTO> getLibraryItemsPojo(@Valid @RequestBody DataTablesInput input, Function<LibraryItem,LibraryItemDataTableDTO> converter) {
        return libraryItemsdtr.findAll(input, converter);

    }
```

this is my dto

```
public LibraryItemDataTableDTO(Long id, String barcode) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.barcode = barcode;

}
Long id;

String barcode;
//getters setters
public LibraryItemDataTableDTO() {}

}
```

this is the entity

```
public class LibraryItem {

 public LibraryItem() {}

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonView(DataTablesOutput.View.class)
    private Long id;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "FkStatus")
    private MetaStatus status;



    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "FkLibraryCategory")
    private LibraryCategory libraryCategory;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "item")
    @JsonView(DataTablesOutput.View.class)
    private List<LibraryItemLanguage> itemLanguageList;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "item")
    private List<LibraryItemOpt> itemOptList;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "item")
    @JsonView(DataTablesOutput.View.class)
    private List<LibraryItemImages> itemImageList;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CreatedBy")
    private User CreatedBy;


    @Column(name = "CreatedAt")
    private Date created;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "UpdatedBy")
    private User UpdatedBy;


    @Column(name = "UpdatedAt")
    private Date updated;

    @JsonView(DataTablesOutput.View.class)
    private String barcode;

}
```

my repository

```
public interface LibraryItemsDataTables extends DataTablesRepository<LibraryItem, Long> {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old question but than i think i should post my finding so it will helpful

You can resolve this by creating a method in **LibraryItemDataTableDTO** which return the implementation for converter see the below code using your Entity and DTO class

```
public static Function<LibraryItem , LibraryItemDataTableDTO> getConverter() {
        return (LibraryItem item) -> {
            return new LibraryItemDataTableDTO(item.getId(),item.getBarCode());
        };
    }
```

after this your controller looks like

```
@JsonView(DataTablesOutput.View.class)
    @RequestMapping(value = "api/libraryitemspojo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public DataTablesOutput<LibraryItemDataTableDTO> getLibraryItemsPojo(@Valid @RequestBody DataTablesInput input, Function<LibraryItem,LibraryItemDataTableDTO> converter) {
        return libraryItemsdtr.findAll(input, LibraryItemDataTableDTO.getConverter());

    }
```

this solution works in my case too. :)